# How do I provide token in the query string for every subsequent m3u8 file request using html video tag on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, http-live-streaming, hls.js, clappr

I'm having trouble playing  HLS video on my iPhone cause the hls video URL is protected by an authorization token.
I'm using [clappr](https://github.com/clappr/clappr/) library(where I can pass the authorization header) to play HLS videos and everything is working fine except for iOS devices. Since iOS doesn't provide the necessary APIs used by the HLS libraries. What might be the best option for me to pass the authorization header(or query string token) in plain HTML video tag.

```
<video src="http://example.com/path/mymovie.m3u8?token=<my_token>" controls></video>
```

Since, just adding the `token` query string to the master m3u8 file will not pass the same `token` to the other playlist m3u8 files.

Comment: i have the same problem, 
found any solution to fix this ?

Comment: Sadly I haven't, because of this issue, safari is unable to my videos.